# jQuery mb-extruder with bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, panel

I wanted to use slider panel to show reminders on the right of my div / page. For that I used mb-extruder. It was working fine until I included the bootstrap library. It shows the panel button with some gap. I checked all the properties using developer tools of Chrome. Except there is a width of the panel button (which was defined as 100%), there is no deviation. I am not sure why the width getting reduced when I add bootstrap. There is no sign of explicit css being applied. Here are reference images.

[image: Without bootstrap] without bootstrap

[image: With bootstrap] with bootstrap

Comment: Please provide a fiddle, codepen, live link, or the like so that we can help you more effectively.

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap sets the box-sizing to border-box. extruder wants content-box. Just add this (preferably after all the other styles)

```
<style>
    .flap{
        box-sizing: content-box;
    }
</style>
```